# Getting wrong values when reading numbers from ASCII file with Fortran

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to read a text file of values into Fortran. The values themselves are separated by spaces:

```
2.606981379902478 .3902892116613899 24.99728028637431
2.38197636218735 .3006054545842558 24.23058044177526
2.321277032042287 .3050883909675102 23.19812552848228
```

I'm trying to open the file and read the values from each line into a double-precision floating point array, before writing it back out to the screen.

```
IMPLICIT NONE
PARAMETER, INTEGER       :: DP=KIND(1.0D0)
REAL(DP), DIMENSION(3)   :: vector

OPEN(UNIT=11, FILE="results.txt",  FORM="FORMATTED")
DO
      READ(11, IOSTAT=k) vector
      IF (k .LT. 0) THEN
             EXIT
      END IF

      WRITE(*,*) vector
END DO
```

However, the values that it writes out don't match the values that I'm reading in. For example, for the first line, it prints

```
1.4821969375237396E-323   6.9022845013543139E-310   2.0735816580202116E-317
```

What's the explanation for the difference between the values I'm reading in and the values its printing out? I've looked quite a bit already online and I'm not finding an explanation or a solution. If it helps, I'm using fortran 90 and compiling with gfortran.

Comment: You don't specify a format for the formatted read, so I'd expect `k` to be positive (and non-zero).

Comment: Thanks. You don't know how long I've been staring at this without seeing that typo.

Comment: I closed as duplicate even though the problem exhibits differently, just the cause is the same. If someone disagrees it could be reopened, but then it is closable as a typo anyway.